# java: package jdk.incubator.foreign is not visible error in Java 15

Tags: java

So I have downloaded JDK 15 - OpenJDK .

Running in Intelij the following code

```
import jdk.incubator.foreign.MemorySegment;  //The problem seems to occur here in this import

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args){

      MemorySegment m = MemorySegment.allocateNative(400L);

   }

 }
```

In inteliJ I have gone to File -> Project Structure -> Project SDK -> selected 15

In Application configurations (Intelij run project) I have declared JRE 15 (java version 15.0.2)

I receive the following error

```
C:\Users\repositories\java15project\src\main\untitled\src\Application.java:2:21
java: package jdk.incubator.foreign is not visible
(package jdk.incubator.foreign is declared in module jdk.incubator.foreign, which is not in the module graph)
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: So if I want to use JDK 15 and jdk.incubator I don't have any other choice than the modularization of my project?

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/flapi_recipeNo001

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run with option `--add-modules jdk.incubator.foreign`

Alternatively, create a `module-info.java` file, e.g. like this:

```
module my.module.name.here {
    requires jdk.incubator.foreign;
}
```

Comment: the second option worked like charm. The first though didn't.

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos `java --add-modules jdk.incubator.foreign my.package.Application` didn't work? It did for me. Remember to put VM options *before* the class name.

Comment: @Boug you need to add that under `VM options`

Comment: I found in my IntelliJ that, I not only needed to add --add-modules jdk.incubator.foreign into my VM options under Run, but also needed to add --add-modules jdk.incubator.foreign under Preferences -> Build, Execution, Development -> Compiler -> Java Compiler -> Additional command line parameters

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 with Intellij 2021.2.3, none of the option work, neither the VM options (which work on MacOS+IntelliJ), neither adding --add-module to compiler options, neither adding module.info : all of them separately or all together lead to the same originally mentioned error message. Suggestions appreciated :)

Comment: I fixed by also forcing the target bytecode version to be the one of the VM I am running on.